# How do you add a click event handler for a ClassifiedTextRun in QuickInfo tip in a Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, vspackage, vsx

I am working through the VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples project on Github. The quick info project is working fine.

I just want to know how to make a ClassifiedTextRun ( word in the tip ) clickable and perform some action when the word is clicked.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vs-editor-api/tree/main/samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the Visual Studio SDK needed to be updated to the latest stable version to see the overload that takes a navigation action.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/):)